# Camel route from JMS to multiple Kafka clusters transactionally

Tags: apache-camel, jms, apache-kafka

I'm trying to configure camel to read from single JMS queue and publish to 2 different Kafka cluster.

My configuration is something like

```
from("jms:queueName?concurrentConsumers=1")
  .transacted()
  .to("kafka:host1:port1?topic=kafkaTopic")
  .to("kafka:host2:port2?topic=kafkaTopic")
```

My problem is how to configure the process to be in-transaction, meaning if it fail to write to one of Kafka, it should rollback the the write from the other Kafka and the message stays in JMS queue.

In my integration test when I shutdown the second kafka and publish message to JMS queue, the message still arrives at the first kafka.

Comment: Well, I think kafka do not support transactions, however I think it can be done through topic compaction eventually. That's mean if you send a message with a key and some value to a kafka topic, then you have to send a message with same key and null value to nullify it. When cleanup kicks in they will remove both messages, but only on inactive segments!!!